# How to pass the CSRF token between rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf

Our rails3 application talks to another rails application exposed as REST functions. We get the following warning post migration to rails3 on all POST calls made to the REST services.

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

How should we pass the csrf token on the wire when we make a POST call to the REST services, the ApplicationController has protect_from_forgery method and the call also lands on the handle_unverified_request call. We use HTTP basic auth to authenticate and it seems to work fine. What should we do to resolve this issue.

Comment: is the communication between the backends of the two applications or is it possible for the "front-end" user to call the REST functions directly?

Comment: The UI invokes a button action, which in turn causes the controller to issues this call to the REST service.

Comment: by controller you mean the rails controller from Application A makes a request to a controller from Application B?

Answer (score 13):

Ok now I'll give it a shot to answer your question.

CSRF tokens are "session dependent" this means the user must share a session with the application he is communicating with. This means a request must have been made before he submits the actual form which is the case for standard HTML forms where the form is displayed before it is submitted so there's room to generate a CSRF token for this user.

Let's call the Application which serves the UI Button App1 and the one hosting the REST Service App2.

The User shares a session with App1 and gets the UI Button served by App1. Once the user clicks the button a request to App1 is made, and App1 makes a request to the REST Service of App2.

Conclusion: The user doesn't share a session with App2 but your App1 has a session with App2. This concludes in two things:

1. The User is not vulnerable to Cross-Site-Forgery on App2 because he doesn't have a session on that server. So if I post a something like `<img src="http://app2.com/rest-service/destroy>` here, App2 wouldn't recognise me because I don't share a session with App2 and nothing happens.
2. You can implement your own security measures on the REST Service to secure it from the public:

   - Authentication by HTTP Basic Auth
   - Authentication by an API Key
   - ....

This means you can drop the CSRF protection on the REST Service and stay on the safe side as long as user's can't make direct calls via AJAX etc.

**Addition**

CSRF protects your site from submitted forms that do not come from your origin (actually this applies to POSTed forms only since they usually manipulate data.

The big scenario is: I'm the attacker and I'd like to update your users account name to "Mr. Potatoe" the way I'd do that is to place a hidden form on my website which gets POSTed to `Yourdomain.com/account` with a hidden field like `account[name]="Mr. Potatoe"`. Now what happens without CSRF protection? My browser submits the form, and sends the authentication cookie with it and my name is now "Mr. Potatoe". What happens with CSRF protection? My browsers submits the form and sends the cookie but the form has no CSRF token so the request gets rejected. Now is there a way as attacker to get the CSRF token under these circumstances? The answer is no. Maybe you ask yourself....

- What if I place a hidden iframe on my site which points to `Yourdomain.com/account/edit` and just copy the hidden field containing the token? - Answer: It won't work because of same origin policy, you can't read whats inside an iframe if its content doesn't come from your domain.
- What if I make an AJAX call in the background to get the token? Answer: It won't work because using pure AJAX you are bound to the same origin policy as well.

Now let's get to the point: I can't send a hidden AJAX call from my page to yours to harm your user who is on my site.

What does it mean? You can implement a before filter which checks if `request.xhr?` is true or whether the user agent is something like "My REST Client XY" because this can't be forged by a cross site request in a >>browser<<. So if this is the case you can ignore/disable the CSRF protection.

By the way if you want to make an AJAX request within your site you can get the CSRF token like this:

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

See the Rails UJS Script: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L81

NOTE: this only protects you from cross site forgery and nothing else....

Comment: useful.  But what if the REST service can be called both as a REST service AND via html pages?  Say you're writing tests against a rails app in ruby and want to be able to test posting forms but the CRSF failure noted above is happening.  Seems like we have to get a session and get the CSRF token to pass back for the post. but how?

Comment: for the testing case, it appears something like this might be useful: https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client  since it lets one get the cookies which should have the CSRF token in it. (???)

Comment: Afaik the csrf token is embedded as hidden field in the form tag and definitley in the <head> section as <meta> tag.

Comment: I made some additions to my answer I hope it helps.